# Multiple Task Lists Polling Using Flow

Tags: priority-queue, amazon-swf

I'm trying to figure out how utilizing SWF Flow framework, I can have my activity worker poll multiple task list.  The use case is for having two different priorities for activity tasks that need to be completed.

Bouns points if someone uses glisten and can point out a way to achieve that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for a single ActivityWorker to poll on multiple task lists. The reason for such design is that each poll request can take up to a minute due to long poll. If a few such polls feed into a single threaded activity implemenation it is not clear how to deal with conflicts that arise if tasks are received on multiple task lists.

Until the SWF natively supports priority task lists the solution is to instantiate one ActivityWorker per task list (priority) and deal with conflicts yourself.